# Fetch all unique data from mysql with PHP distinct

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck on fetching unique data from MySql Database by PHP `Distinct`. I want to fetch all the data from the table but in a particular field '**ccTitle**' should remove duplicate entries. My Query is as follows-

```
"SELECT DISTINCT(*) FROM conferencecreate WHERE ccFlag = 1 AND ccStartingDate >= '$nowTime'"
```

But it's not working. I discovered `Distinct` is working individually for a field. Is there another to solve this issue?

Let me know please.

TQ

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the desired result and an example of what you're actually getting?

Comment: Distinct returns only distinct records.  If there is one thing different in a row, it will be distinct.  If you're getting too much back, limit the fields you are pulling.  Like, if you only need distinct names, just pull that column.

Comment: @CindyMeister, Yes, check it out following link-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5SxUM9G7rObMWpBNC1sbDltVU0/view?usp=sharing


in my query I am not using distinct. In snap, you can see there are some duplicate entry. I wanna remove duplicate entries..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this query:

```
SELECT *
TABLE table
GROUP BY column
```

You can write this query with DISTINCT statement like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON column *
FROM table
```

Comment: In my case, GROUP BY is working nicewhile while DISTINCT ON has some sort of errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to `SELECT DISTINCT` for each field you want non-duplicated data ..

IE

```
SELECT DISTICT ON item1,item2 *
FROM table WHERE something = 'something'
```

Comment: Well, I want to fetch all entries from database alongside with Distinct the titles of my entries. Is that possible?

Comment: Showing some sample data and your expected result would likely help us help you more quickly.

Comment: ^^ I agree ..  You didn't pose that in your OP ...  Show us a couple of example rows (with duplicate data) and what the desired output should look like.

Comment: I have edited my post .. Was that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I found the appropriate answer for my question. Instead of using **distinct**, **group by** can be used to solve this issue.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM conferencecreate WHERE ccFlag = 1 AND ccStartingDate >= '$nowTime' GROUP BY ccTitle");
```

It's working for me perfectly.

Thank you all.

Comment: if you are using `GROUP BY` without any aggregate function(s) then it will act the same as `DISTINCT`, so in this case there is no difference between `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`.  Some would argue that in this case it's OK because "it works".  So does cutting paper with a knife ..  But scissors are the correct tool :-)

Comment: Well, I believe so also that literally no difference between DISTINCT and GROUP BY, however, for me GROUP BY is working nicely. TQ